# Step Functions Passing Parameters down to lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am building a State Machine that launches EC2 instances. Afterwards, I am manipulating the EC2 instance but to do so I need the newly created EC2 instances InstanceId which is returned in the Lambda function. How can I get the return value from my first Lambda to be passed to following Lambda functions?

I have tried "InputPath", "OutputPath", & "ResultPath" but every time I attempt it cancels the Lambda function. Not sure why this is (maybe fixing this would fix my problem).

```
{
   "Comment": "My State Machine",
   "StartAt": "Launch Instance",
   "States": {
     "Launch Instance": {
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource": "Lambda",
     "Parameters": {
      "FunctionName": "My lambda",
      "Payload": {
        "Input": {
           "ImageId": "My Image"
         }
       }
     },
     "Next": "wait_ten_seconds"
       },
       "wait_ten_seconds": {
     "Type": "Wait",
     "Seconds": 10,
     "Next": "Create Image"
   },
     "Create Image":{
       "Type": "Task",
       "Resource": "Lambda",
       "Parameters":{
       "FunctionName": "My Lambda"
     },
       "Next": "Terminate Instance"
     },
      "Terminate Instance": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "Lambda",
        "Parameters": {
          "FunctionName": "My lambda"
        },
         "End": true
       }
     }
   }
```

It works if I hard-code the payload in but (obviously) hard-coding is not the goal. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t specify `ResultPath`, every task output will overwrite the previous input. Therefore, given that Launch Instance returns `{"instance_id": "xxx"}`, a possible strategy could be:

1. In Luanch Instance, `"ResultPath": "$.launch_instance.output"`
2. In Create Image, `"ResultPath": "$.create_image.output"`
3. In Terminate Instance, `"InputPath": "$.launch_instance.output"`

Now you can get the value using `event["instance_id"]`